# JW Player: No suitable players found

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I have the following javascript on my web page:

```
    jwplayer(elementId).setup({
        'modes': [
                    { type: 'html5' },
                    { type: 'flash', src: '/jwplayer/player.swf' }
                ],
        file: videoUrl,
        width: width + "px",
        height: height + "px"
    });
```

When running the page in Google Chrome (*version 20.0.1132.57 m*) I get the error:

> No suitable players found

I've debugged my code, and all variables are passing the correct values. Also I've used this same script on other applications, and they are working fine.

Why am I receiving this error?

Comment: What is the file extension on `videoURL`?

Comment: @merv `.mp4`. I've tested this same video file on other applications running JW Player and this has worked fine.

Comment: Very strange.  What does calling `document.createElement("video").canPlayType("video/mp4")` in your console say?  If I were you, I'd debug through the **jwplayer.js** code, adding a breakpoint at the `_embedPlayer()` method.  You need to see what's happening there.

Comment: @Curt What version jwplayer are you running?

Comment: @Curt : hey have you got any solution about this problem?

Comment: Hi, just an idea, do you have any ad blocker enabled on your Chrome ?

Answer (score 1):

Install the adobe flash player please find the below mentioned link
http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/

Answer (score -1):

I think this error can appear when, wrong URL, or wrong setup object proveded.

Try to check your url. Also you should not use PX here "width + "px"," leave it width: 200 for example.